# How to Hide our dev and stage environments with robots.txt(Live domain)?

Tags: robots.txt

How to disable the dev domain environment in robots.txt file in Live environments.
Dev environment url - www1.dev.com
Live  - [www.Live.com](http://www.Live.com)

Thanks,
Sekhar

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you block it from web crawlers and search engine indexing, it is up to the crawlers to obey the robots.txt. some smaller search engines may ignore this and index you regardless.

Also, if someone has or finds a direct link then they will have access. For a live development environment you ideally want to have some form of authentication - be it IP, a key or a session cookie.

Comment: Yes they can find the dev environment url from the below search in Google.com. They used to find the deve urls by using the below command line in google search "site:domainurl.com" . Thanks for your immediate reply.

Comment: Yes, it's important to not just deindex them from Google but also protect the production endpoints if they are sensitive. I recommend you only let authorised IPs access the development backend. That way it does not matter if they find the Dev URLs